# good variable name: the number of process to go

Tags: variables, naming-conventions, naming

I'd like to know a good name of a variable although I'm not sure this kind of question is in scope of SO.

I have a variable which holds the number of processes to go. What is a good name for `x` in below code?

```
int x = getTheNumberOfProcess();
while(x > 0){
  if(someCondition()){
    x -= 1;
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: `processesRemaining` ?

Comment: `processCount` or `proc_ct`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question of how to name variables has existed for time immemorial. One approach (both loved and loathed) at least attempts to deal with systematically.  "Hungarian Notation", http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation.

In Hungarian, a variable that contains a count of something begins with "c", so in that approach you would name it cProcess. (The thing being counted is usually kept in singular, not plural.)

Also very popular but not sure if it's as "official doctrine" would be to prefix with "num", i.e., "numProcesses".

At the end of the day the goal is readability and maintainability. Anything more descriptive than "x" is preferred...

Answer (score 0):

A good name should describe what the variable holds. `numProcesses` is a pretty decent name, but it doesn't convey the entire context. By reading the code, `x` seems to be the outer limit of times `doSomething()` will be executed, in case `someCondition()` is always `true`. So how about `processLimit`?